# Loading Django sites (contrib.sites) in initial_data

Tags: django, testing, fixtures, sites

Is there a way to load some initial sites (from the sites framework) thorough initial_data fixtures, so that I can avoid setting them up in each of my tests?

I'm having this error trying to put it there:

```
DeserializationError: Invalid model identifier: 'django.contrib.sites.site'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `django.contrib` part.